# How to change the check type for checkbox in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I want to use a cross instead of a tick on my check-box.

Comment: Hi @Abhi_Dev, you are going to need to give us more information

Comment: Hi i want to put cross(x) in checkbox instead of check.<br> when we open fillable pdf in Adobe lifecycle designer, show 4 or 5 styles like  cross ,check, diamond,square etc and when altered it to cross it show me nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it by setting the CheckType field.

`myRadioCheckField.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CROSS;`

You can check the other types available [here](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/f29f3b5e-c277-a2e6-4f08-f31d705c6d84.htm).