# Adding form elements to a table with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, pdf-form

I'm trying to create a PDF document that is essentially a list of users in a table format. I need the table to have checkboxes in it. So far, I have the table and the checkboxes separately but I cannot find a way to get the checkboxes in the table. I think I need to add them using the AddCell() method.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create the document, filestream, writer
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\test\User List.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, file);

        try
        {
            // metadata
            doc.AddAuthor("Test User");
            doc.AddCreator("Test Document");
            doc.AddKeywords("Test Document");
            doc.AddSubject("Test Document");
            doc.AddTitle("Test Document - Test User");

            // open up the PDF document
            doc.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            Font _bf = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9);

            // create a table
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("User List"));

            PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateCheckBox(writer);
            field.SetWidget(new Rectangle(40, 500, 60, 530), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
            field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
            field.FieldName = "Delete";
            writer.AddAnnotation(field);

            cell.Colspan = 3;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0 = left, 1 = center, 2 = right
            cell.VerticalAlignment = 1;
            table.AddCell("No.");
            table.AddCell("Users");
            table.AddCell("Delete");

            // create form fields
            PdfAppearance[] onOff = new PdfAppearance[2];
            Rectangle rect;
            PdfFormField checkbox;
            RadioCheckField _checkbox;

            onOff[0] = cb.CreateAppearance(10, 10);
            onOff[0].Rectangle(1, 1, 8, 8);
            onOff[0].Stroke();

            onOff[1] = cb.CreateAppearance(10, 10);
            onOff[1].SetRGBColorFill(255, 128, 128);
            onOff[1].Rectangle(1, 1, 8, 8);
            onOff[1].FillStroke();
            onOff[1].MoveTo(1, 1);
            onOff[1].LineTo(9, 9);
            onOff[1].MoveTo(1, 9);
            onOff[1].LineTo(9, 1);
            onOff[1].Stroke();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                table.AddCell(i.ToString());
                table.AddCell("User " + i);
                //rect = new Rectangle(400, 675 - i*40, 415, 663 - i*40);
                rect = new Rectangle(400, 735 - i * 40, 415, 723 - i * 40);
                _checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "User "+(i+1), "Yes");
                checkbox = _checkbox.CheckField;
                checkbox.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", onOff[0]);
                checkbox.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "On", onOff[1]);
                writer.AddAnnotation(checkbox);

                // this is where I am trying to add the checkbox to the table
                // what can I add to AddCell() to make the checkbox show up?
                table.AddCell();
                //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("User " + (i + 1), _bf), 50, 665 - i * 40, 0);
            }

            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            doc.Add(table);

        }
        catch(DocumentException dex)
        {
            throw (dex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // close
            doc.Close();
            writer.Close();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to do this using iTextSharp? Maybe there is a better library to use?

Comment: I suppose what I could do is draw lines around the form elements, like this: | number | name | checkbox                                                And then draw lines above or below them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll reference the [iText website](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=161) showing how to pass a field to a custom `IPdfPCellEvent` implementation and [how to create that that custom class](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=162) and recreate it below in C#.

First, create a class the implements the `IPdfPCellEvent`:

```
public class ChildFieldEvent : IPdfPCellEvent {
    /** A parent field to which a child field has to be added. */
    protected PdfFormField parent;
    /** The child field that has to be added */
    protected PdfFormField kid;
    /** The padding of the field inside the cell */
    protected float padding;

    /**
     * Creates a ChildFieldEvent.
     * @param parent the parent field
     * @param kid the child field
     * @param padding a padding
     */
    public ChildFieldEvent(PdfFormField parent, PdfFormField kid, float padding) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.kid = kid;
        this.padding = padding;
    }

    /**
     * Add the child field to the parent, and sets the coordinates of the child field.
     */
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb) {
        parent.AddKid(kid);
        kid.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                    rect.GetLeft(padding),
                                                    rect.GetBottom(padding),
                                                    rect.GetRight(padding),
                                                    rect.GetTop(padding)
                                                    ),
                                                    PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT
                                                    );
    }
}
```

Then just set the `CellEvent` on any cells that should have fields in them.

```
//File to create
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

//Standard PDF creation, nothing special here
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            //Create a root form object that we'll add "children" to. This way we don't have to add each "child" annotation to the writer
            var root = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(writer);
            root.FieldName = "root";

            //Create a two column table
            var t = new PdfPTable(2);

            //Add a basic cell
            t.AddCell("First Name");

            //Create our textfield, the rectangle that we're passing in is ignored and doesn't matter
            var tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0), "first-name");

            //Create a new cell
            var cell = new PdfPCell();

            //Set the cell event to our custom IPdfPCellEvent implementation
            cell.CellEvent = new ChildFieldEvent(root, tf.GetTextField(), 1);

            //Add the cell to our table
            t.AddCell(cell);

            //Add the table to the document
            doc.Add(t);

            //IMPORTANT! Add the root annotation to the writer which also adds all of the child annotations
            writer.AddAnnotation(root);


            //Clean up
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't think about that. I did look at that site but I guess I should have looked harder, I always seem to panic when I can't find something and I forget to calm down and delve further into the problems.

Comment: Whenever you do a search for iTextSharp related solutions and can't find anything, also try searching for iText since that's the parent project and has been around for much longer.

Comment: I have another question, you know how the checkbox field has a circle in it after you've checked it? How can I change that to show an "X"? I've set up an appearance for when the user is clicking on it. When the user clicks the field, they see an "X", but afterward, it's just a black dot.

Comment: Can you convert your comment to a new question?

Comment: Yes, I will. Sorry, I forgot to do that

Comment: Upon further research, I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9892245/1324729