# Make a PdfCell Editable in iTextSharp form

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, tablecell

I am creating a PdfTable from iTextSharp but the pdf containing this table does not allow editing in its cells.

**How can I make sure that the cell contents are editable in resulting pdf?**

```
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(columnsToAdd);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right

        Font headerFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
        Font bodyFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 6f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
        PdfPCell cEmpId = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Emp ID", headerFont));
        PdfPCell cEmpAge = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Emp Age", headerFont));


       table.AddCell(cEmpId);
       table.AddCell(cEmpAge);

       foreach(Child child in childData)
       {

         PdfPCell cellEmpID = new PdfPCell {FixedHeight = 10f};
         cellEmpID.Phrase = (new Phrase(child.Emp_ID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                          bodyFont));

         PdfPCell cellEmpAge = new PdfPCell {Phrase = (new Phrase(child.Emp_Age, bodyFont))};

         table.AddCell(cellEmpID);
         table.AddCell(cellEmpAge);
     }
```

**EDIT 1:**
Based on Chris's answer, I am going to try out the following code, but not sure at this time.

```
       //WITHIN THE LOOP IN MY CODE ABOVE ADD THESE LINES FOR EVERY PDF CELL
       //Create our textfield, the rectangle that we're passing in is ignored and doesn't matter
        var tfEmpID = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0), child.Emp_ID);

        //Set the cell event to our custom IPdfPCellEvent implementation
        cellEmpID.CellEvent = new ChildFieldEvent(root, tfEmpID.GetTextField(), 1);

       //THEN OUTSIDE THE LOOP
       //IMPORTANT! Add the root annotation to the writer which also adds all of the child annotations
        writer.AddAnnotation(root);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "editable". Do you want add a form field so that anyone with a PDF program can enter text into it? Or are you trying to embed a font so that someone can open your PDF in the paid Acrobat Pro and change some text?

Comment: I meant anyone who sees that pdf in a certain ASP.Net app should find that field editable. A user in a web app will only see this dynamically generated pdf. Most times they will not have a paid version of Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: If you want text to be editable without requiring certain applications to be installed then you'll need to make a text field. Text field, however, are not part of the normal stream of things like lines, images and text so they need to be handled differently. See this post which explains how to use cell events: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19410562/231316

Comment: I have a feeling this is going down a certain path so let me just get this cleared up right away. Let's say that Alice logs into your site and views a PDF. She then "edits" the field you have made available. What happens next? Does she click a "save" button? Does she just print and then closes her browser thus losing all changes? Do you need to validate the next in any way?

Comment: The dynamically generated pdf is then emailed to a certain email address after necessary changes are made ( only if needed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added code under 'EDIT 1' in my original post but I am going to try it later. Does it look ok?

Comment: *Does it look ok* - hard to tell without knowing `ChildFieldEvent`.