# C# iTextSharp CellEvent not applying correctly for FormField

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm attempting to create a `FormField` in C# using iTextSharp so that the user can electronically sign/fill out the resultant pdf. I took the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407179/adding-form-elements-to-a-table-with-itextsharp), but am unable to get it to work for my specific problem.

```
private static void AddPrintedNameCell(PdfPTable table, PDFReport pdf, int index)
{
                                                         //also tried 0, 0 here
    TextField tf = new TextField(pdf.Writer, new Rectangle(35, 340, 300, 350), "PrintedNameCell_" + index);
    var root = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(pdf.Writer);
    root.Name = "Root_" + index;

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Printed Name: \r\n_______________________________________\r\n\r\n"));
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    cell.CellEvent = new ChildFieldEvent(root, tf.GetTextField(), 1);

    table.AddCell(cell);
    pdf.Writer.AddAnnotation(root);
}        

public class ChildFieldEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        /** A parent field to which a child field has to be added. */
        protected PdfFormField parent;
        /** The child field that has to be added */
        protected PdfFormField kid;
        /** The padding of the field inside the cell */
        protected float padding;

        /**
         * Creates a ChildFieldEvent.
         * @param parent the parent field
         * @param kid the child field
         * @param padding a padding
         */
        public ChildFieldEvent(PdfFormField parent, PdfFormField kid, float padding)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.kid = kid;
            this.padding = padding;
        }

        /**
         * Add the child field to the parent, and sets the coordinates of the child field.
         */
        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb)
        {                
            parent.AddKid(kid);
            kid.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                        rect.GetLeft(padding),
                                                        rect.GetBottom(padding),
                                                        rect.GetRight(padding),
                                                        rect.GetTop(padding)
                                                        ),
                                                        PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT
                                                        );
        }
    }
```

When `ChildFieldEvent` fires, `rect.GetLeft(padding)`, `rect.GetRight(padding)`, etc. all return `0`, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing.

Comment: when you step through the code when you call the `ChildFieldEvent what is the value if padding..? are you overriding it somewhere else in code that you are not showing us..?

Comment: @MethodMan padding comes through as 1.0. I'm not overriding this anywhere, the code above should be the only relevant code.

Comment: So, in AddPrintedNameCell() you pass a Rectangle, but CellLayout() makes use of a iTextShart.text.Rectangle. I'm betting that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: The Rectangle I pass in is an iTextSharp.text.Rectangle. See http://imgur.com/CIdYIsU for screenshot.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry but I don't know iTextSharp, but I see you construct pdfCell with a phrase instead of with empty arguments. Could it be that when you add the cell, it calls that callback twice, once for the phrase with default rectangle (0-based) and once for the textField?

Comment: @deckeresq Unfortunately your code is not self-contained. Furthermore, the definition and use of your table are not explained in text form either, so it is unclear how to make your code runable. Thus, your issue could not be reproduced.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the response! I actually solved the problem months ago, and I believe it was something in the listed code, though I don't remember for sure. I'll go back and look at what happened, then post an answer.