# Itextsharp not rendering cells

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext

I am trying to display a cell in iTextSharp  Version in a second page but it does not display the cells for some reason here is the code

```
 float dpi = 100f;
            float widthInches = (3900f * 1.1f) / dpi;
            float heightInches = (2775f * 1.1f) / dpi;

            // Increase the size of the Rectangle object by 10%
            float width = widthInches * 1.1f * 72f;
            float height = heightInches * 1.1f * 72f;

            var pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(width, height);
            var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(width, height);

            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(rect, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream(dest, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
...
 document.NewPage();
            iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.CaraB["1"]);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            image.ScaleToFit(3400, 2400);
            document.Add(image1);

             PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

            // Create header cells
            PdfPCell header1 = new PdfPCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk("Logros", iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD))));
            PdfPCell header2 = new PdfPCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk("Horas", iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD))));

            // Add header cells to table
            table.AddCell(header1);
            table.AddCell(header2);

            // Create data cells
            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk("Unlogro", iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10))));
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk("12", iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10))));
            document.close();
```

the output is the following
[![PDF output][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni8WA.png

Comment: Your haven't added the _PDFTable_ to the document. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159051/10024425

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid i had placed in my code I forgot to add it here... I am sorry I have updated my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solved it

```
document.NewPage();
            iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.CaraB["1"]);
            image1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            image1.ScaleToFit(3400, 2400);
            document.Add(image1);

            // create a new PdfPTable object with two columns
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);


            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph();
            paragraph.SpacingAfter = 15f;
           
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell( );
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("HEADER1", new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 74, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("HEADER2", new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 74, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly that you have instantiated the table with a 2 column width, but your first cell has a colspan of 3?

Comment: changed to only two cells and still nothing maybe it has to do with the placement in the page, since the image is quite large