How can I export a DataGridView to a PDF with a watermark using iTextSharp in VB.NET?
I'm working on a VB.NET Windows Forms application and need to export the data from a DataGridView to a PDF file. Additionally, I need to include a watermark image in the background of each page of the PDF.
I’m using the iTextSharp library for PDF generation. Here’s the current code I have:
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Layout
Imports iText.Layout.Element
Imports iText.IO.Image
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas
Imports System.IO

Public Sub ExportDataGridViewToPdfWithWatermark(dgvRegularUser As DataGridView, filePath As String, watermarkPath As String)
    Try
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(watermarkPath) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("File path or watermark path cannot be empty.")
        End If

        If Not File.Exists(watermarkPath) Then
            Throw New FileNotFoundException("Watermark image not found.", watermarkPath)
        End If

        Using writer As New PdfWriter(filePath)
            Using pdf As New PdfDocument(writer)
                Dim document As New Document(pdf)
                Dim table As New Table(dgvRegularUser.ColumnCount)
                table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))

                For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvRegularUser.Columns
                    table.AddHeaderCell(column.HeaderText)
                Next

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvRegularUser.Rows
                    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                            Dim cellValue As String = If(cell.Value IsNot Nothing, cell.Value.ToString(), String.Empty)
                            table.AddCell(cellValue)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

                document.Add(table)
                AddWatermarkBackground(pdf, watermarkPath)
            End Using
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("PDF Exported Successfully with Watermark!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error generating PDF: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddWatermarkBackground(pdf As PdfDocument, watermarkPath As String)
    Dim numberOfPages As Integer = pdf.GetNumberOfPages()

    For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfPages
        Dim page As PdfPage = pdf.GetPage(i)
        Dim pdfCanvas As New PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdf)

        Dim watermarkImage As ImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(watermarkPath)
        Dim watermark As New iText.Layout.Element.Image(watermarkImage)
        watermark.SetOpacity(0.3F)
        watermark.SetAutoScale(True)
        watermark.SetFixedPosition(0, 0, page.GetPageSize().GetWidth(), page.GetPageSize().GetHeight())

        Dim document As New Document(pdf)
        document.Add(watermark)
    Next
End Sub

Issues:
Error Generating PDF: I'm receiving an error with the message "Unknown PdfException" and the PDF file generated seems to be empty or corrupted.
Watermark Position: The watermark appears to be incorrectly positioned or not visible on the final PDF.
Questions:

How can I troubleshoot the "Unknown PdfException" error?
Is there a correct way to add a watermark to each page in the PDF?
Are there any common mistakes in the code above that might be causing the PDF
to not render correctly?

Any help or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

You may consider trying to create a PDF file without a watermark first. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159051/10024425

"How can I troubleshoot the "Unknown PdfException" error?" - look at the details of the exception, not just the message string. In particular there is the stack trace and possibly a causing exception.

That being said, opening multiple new Document instances for a single PdfDocument is probably a bad idea.
